# Best Architecture Pattern for Waterfall API Calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I’m trying to implement an architecture where I have customers with order and shipment history. I’m trying to import that data to another system using API calls but the issue is I cannot import all the customer data using single API call. I am using promises to create a waterfall pattern where once the customer info is imported, then order import request is made and then the shipment import API request is made.

I’m trying to leverage AWS Lambda, SQS, Cloudwatch etc. for these connections. The issue that I see is with the sequenced API calls.

Since there are three API calls happening to import the customer data, the error rate of connection failure, plus manual management and log tracking, all pose a big issue. If let’s say the order API call fails then the shipment API call cannot happen.

I’m confused on how the log tracking can be simplified or automated. How the error rate can be reduced and how the data can be migrated if failure happens at any api connection. Any other AWS service I can leverage? Or any more SQS queues I can use for orders and shipment individually?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a saga – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696171/how-to-achieve-immediate-consistency-in-microservice-architecture

Comment: At a glance this sounds like the sort of things StepFunctions was designed for.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, It sounds like you're building a workflow, and looking for [Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html)

You basically break down your workflow into a state machine, design that state machine ([tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-tasks.html) and [transitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-transitions.html) between states) in Step Functions, and it will manage the state for you.  Typically the tasks will run in AWS Lambda.

In general, the implementation of your API call will simply be a call to start the particular step function that does the workflow you want to start.

In your case, it's a pretty linear state machine - call service A, then B, then C. You'll want to define what kind of transition and activity takes place under error conditions too (notify your customer? give up? other?).